# Drawing sine and cosine wave Android

Tags: android, drawing, wave, trigonometry

I want to draw a cosine wave from an angle in my Android app but i don't know how to do this. Can anyone explain me how to resolve this problem step by step? Thank you.

Comment: see the fallowing link https://github.com/signed/achartengine

Comment: Please check the [question check list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: keshav, I've tried to import the code in Eclipse but it doesn't work. What part of the code of the page i have to put in eclipse to test it? Because it gives me error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). It is a graphing library that was built to generate graphs for Android applications.

Another alternative is Google's [Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

**[EDIT]**

Alternative: http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/

Comment: Thank for you answer, but the problem is that achartengine only represent a part of the wave sine and cosine (one cycle). I want to represent the wave across all the axis x. Which part of achartengine can i modify to get this? Thanks

Comment: @DvApps I've added another link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that link explains how to force a view to be square but what i need is scrolling the axis x to left and rigth and continue viewing the sine and cosine wave too, that is drawing the sine wave not only from 0 to 360 degrees, else more degrees on left or right.